# Is there anything that stacks with the haste spell or speed enchantment

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization

As the title says I am looking for any abilities, spells, enchants, ect that would stack with [haste](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/haste)/[speed](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/speed) (Preferably speed). I am attempting to build a character who hits A LOT. I know I have seen something somewhere that stacked with speed but I cannot find it anywhere now.

The build I am attempting will be using multiweapon fighting with a speed enchant on each weapon he uses.

EDIT:

To be more specific I am looking for abilities, spells ect that will not change the character physically and will only use his weapons.

The answers so far offer good advice but not quite what I am looking for.

YogoZuno is the closest with mentioning the Monk and two weapon fighting tree.

Comment: The Ninja can use a Ki point to get one extra attack (only while doing full-round attack).

Comment: Check feat interactions - there's a way to get your full complement of AoOs out through bullrushes as part of attacks in some convoluted manner.  Cleave and Great Cleave can potentially trigger extra attacks.  Lots of ways to do this with 3.5e backwards compatibility, like lightning mace, snap kick, palm throw, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A monk can flurry built-in, plus when it gets a pool of ki points, it can add an additional attack once per round. So, with Haste and a Ki point, that's 4 attacks per round, before even adding iteratives or natural attacks. A Zen Archer with a ki pool and Haste could fire 4 bowshots a round without iteratives. A Ninja using the Flurry of Stars trick, Rapid Shot and Haste could throw 5 shuriken in a round (at -4 to hit!), assuming he had Quick Draw to draw them all.

If you continue looking at the monk path, the Drunken Master allows a potentially unlimited supply of ki points once you hit 3rd level, allowing you to add an extra attack to a reasonably large number of full attacks.

The two-weapon fighting tree is another option for increasing attacks per round, although it does (in general) limit you to light weapons. Generally, you'll get an attack with each weapon (with slightly less Str bonus on the second), plus haste for 3 attacks, at -2 to hit.

A catfolk with claws and the feat Catfolk Exemplar has two 1d6 natural attacks built-in. The Barbarian Beast totem powers can also provide natural attacks, as can several options on the Tiefling from Blood of Fiends, or the Ranger Natural Weapon style.

Another possible method is using a Magus and touch spells with Spell Combat. When casting a touch spell, a free attack is generated. So, when using a touch spell with Spell Combat, a Magus can have two attacks in a round (at -2). Add haste, and it's 3. Unfortunately, due to Spell Combat being a full round action without being actually being a full attack, you can't really combine this method with any of the other suggestions I've made, except a Monk's Ki pool and natural attacks.

Comment: [A zen archer cannot use Rapid Shot or Manyshot when making a flurry of blows with his bow.](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo---monk-archetypes/zen-archer)

Comment: I made an edit to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I can help with this:
the Aegis (psionics unleashed+unlimited possibilities) can have another set of arms capable of wielding weapons at 8th level
the Monk, with the appropriate fighting styles, can hit even not in his turn (for example when someone tried to hit him but missed)

Comment: I made an edit to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Natural attacks. The multiattack feat, and lots and lots of natural attacks. Each one of them you can get is one more hit per round. If you're combining this with the Aegis lunadir mentioned for 4 arms, you can use the Harness Power Stone customization for metamorphosis, claws of the beast, and bite of the wolf for several natural attacks. Lots of magic items give you another natural attack. Go for the aberrant Aegis archetype for even more natural attacks. You can find even more ways, but this list covers most of the low-hanging fruit.

Comment: I made an edit to the question.

Answer (score -2):

Weapons and natural attacks work differently as you progress in levels. Where number of attacks will increase with your characters base attack bonus, natural attacks can only be used once per natural and secondary natural weapon. To increase your number of attacks beyond the normal for your base attack bonus you could take an exotic weapon proficiency feat in a double one handed weapon such as the Taiaha (UC: Pg.148) on top of your dual wielding, or simply add on additional natural attacks. 
Which ever you choose to go with (keeping in mind that using a normal attack in the same round as a natural attack will treat all other natural attacks as secondary natural attacks) you will need spells and enchants to up your hit chance. Assuming you take levels in caster for haste, your base attack bonus is going to be lower than usual on top of any penalties you take for making additional attacks with double weapons. I would look into buffs like Good Hope / Heroism if you plan on taking levels in bard. Also grabbing potions of Enlarge Person early on are extremely useful! I did this on my dwarf wielding dual dwarvens, the damage you output with one hit makes up for three.